# How to create a keyboard shortcut for custom comment style in Atom

Tags: comments, atom-editor, code-snippets

I did some research but couldn't find any examples. I am trying to achieve the following for JS files.

Let's say that I want to comment the following in Atom:

```
Comment line 1
Comment line 2
Comment line 3
```

When I highlight the above multi line comment and use the keyboard shortcut I created, I want it to display like below:

```
/*
 * Comment line 1
 * Comment line 2
 * Comment line 3
 */
```

How can I create this custom keyboard shortcut ? Is it possible to do this with snippets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially do this by modifying this atom package [block-comment-lines](https://atom.io/packages/block-comment-lines)

have a look at this hack I put together as an example
https://github.com/vishim/block-comment-lines/pull/1/files

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks, I also found a package solves my problem.

[link](https://atom.io/packages/jsdoc)